# Spring->Oracle stored procedure call schema issues

Tags: spring, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, wildfly-8

As part of a refactor, I am trying to change database calls to use Spring 4.1.0.RELEASE in order to handle connections and exceptions and allow result sets to be passed between functions and classes.

I've gotten my MS SQL Server stored procedure calls working fine, but when I tried to execute an Oracle stored procedure, I got the following error message:

```
2014-11-13 15:39:35,836 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /EmailServiceLayer/EmailServletClient/springtest/123: 
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; 
bad SQL grammar [{call SPRING_JDBC_TEMPLATE_TEST()}]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SPRING_JDBC_TEMPLATE_TEST' must be declared
```

I simplified the problem by writing a couple very simple stored procedures that write to a test table: one that takes a parameter and writes and one that takes no parameters and just writes a hardcoded value. These procedures are in the INV schema, which is the same user that my datasource is configured to use.

Eventually I tried running it on my own personal schema, using a datasource configured to use my personal credentials, and it succeeded. I had an admin grant execute all on the procedures in INV, but still no luck. I've confirmed that I can successfully execute simple inline inserts on the INV schema using Spring JdbcTemplate.execute().

My first attempts were using the JdbcTemplate with a CallableStatementCreator of my own definition. I then tried using SimpleJdbcCall, which is what I found out worked on my personal schema. Both ways give the same error message on the INV schema. Here is the code for my latest attempt:

```
SimpleJdbcCall caller = new SimpleJdbcCall(alex3InvTemplate).withProcedureName("spring_jdbc_template_test");
MapSqlParameterSource paramMap = new MapSqlParameterSource();
paramMap.addValue("p_testval", testval);
Map<String, Object> result = caller.execute(paramMap);
```

and my test proc:

```
create or replace
procedure                 spring_jdbc_template_test 
(
  p_testval IN number
)
as
begin

    insert into jdbc_template_test_table values(p_testval);
    commit;

end;
```

My application is running on a Wildfly 8.0.0.Final server. The datasource configurations for the 2 schemas are exactly the same except for the credentials used to log in. I am able to execute the procedures in INV using the same datasource with a basic JDBC CallableStatement and I've confirmed that I can run them in SQL Developer.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know java, just to clarify: 1. you connect to server as user INV, call procedure in schema INV and after that receive error; 2. you connect to your own schema, call procedure in your own schema and all works fine. Yes?

Comment: Correct. Based on that it seems like a db configuration issue with the INV schema, but the call worked when I wasn't using Spring, just a CallableStatement. In fact, it worked with a CallableStatement when I was connecting as a different user than INV

Comment: 1. Try to call it by full name - `INV.SPRING_JDBC_TEMPLATE_TEST` 2. Try to execute `select count(*) from all_procedures
where owner = 'INV' and object_name = 'SPRING_JDBC_TEMPLATE_TEST';` - result has to be >= `1` 3. It could be a "feature" of your framework - in this case I couldn't help

Comment: Already tried the full name a few different ways: by adding .withSchemaName("INV") and .withCatalogName("INV") to the SimpleJdbcCall and adding "INV." in front of the procedure name. For the count query, I get 0 (but no exceptions) when I run it via the Spring JdbcTemplate.queryForList method. When I run it via SQL Developer, I get 1

Comment: Results of select are very strange. First I would want to do after receiving 0 via spring and 1 via SQL Developer here - execute `select user from dual`. Because I don't believe in miracles ;)

Comment: Thank you so much @Dmitry! Turns out I messed up in hooking up the INV datasource and it was still using the SEARCH user. I found the missing link and connected it and it worked. I'm very happy to have gotten past this, but I'm also very embarrassed that I spent so much time working on this bug and didn't catch something so simple. 

I'm still confused as to how I couldn't execute the procedure from the SEARCH user with Spring when it worked using just a CallableStatement. But that hardly matters since I'm fine with using an INV datasource

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I made a silly mistake (typo) and was still using an old datasource and thus a different user than INV. Thanks to Dmitry for making me realize this. Still not sure why I'm unable to execute the procedure from a different user using the Spring framework when I was able to do so using a basic JDBC CallableStatement. It works with the INV datasource though and that's a satisfactory solution for me